# Unable to connect Java to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to connect my java application to `MYSQL(XAMPP)`.

**ConnecttoMsql.java**

```
public void openConnection() throws SQLException{

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqltest","root","");
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println ("Connected may be?");
                connection.close();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ("Not connected?");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

When I tried to call it with `servlet`:

```
try {
        connectMySQL.openConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.dynamicfyp.pkg.ConnecttoMsql.openConnection(ConnecttoMsql.java:39)
    com.dynamicfyp.pkg.ConnecttoMysqlServlet.doGet(ConnecttoMysqlServlet.java:35)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Which one is line 39 in ConnecttoMsql.java?

Comment: In the catch block, you should check connection isn't null before calling a method on it. There's an exception, leading to no connection, so the NPE is expected.

Comment: connection.close(); I have tried commenting it out. It has no error but theres nothing happened

Comment: I am assuming `connectMySQL` is `null`

Comment: Where is the line with connectMySQL where get connection

Comment: how should I fix it @sidgate

Comment: Put the all code of servlet

Comment: `close()` should be in a `finally` block, after you're done using the connection. And, of course, also guarded by a `null`-check.

Answer (score 0):

If your driver is not on the classpath, you'll throw an `ClassNotFoundException` inside your `openConnection()` - but in your `catch()` you reference `connection.close()` on a `null` connection - throwing `NullPointerException`.

If this happened, you'll need to add mysql-connector.jar into your WEB-INF/LIB

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your **catch block**

```
   catch (Exception e) {
    if(connection!=null)    
    connection.close();
    }
```

now you will not face **nullpointer** exception